# Continuous numbering of sentences and/or tables?

Tags: tables, numbering, enumitem

Right now, I'm numbering **example sentences** using the `enumitem`package and `\setlist[enumerate]{label={(\arabic*)},resume}`. Some are just simple, one line sentences like in this example taken from a scientific paper:

[image]

So I simply used

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item a. Example Sentence One \\ b. Example Sentence Two
\end{enumerate}
```

But for some, they have translations underneath, and I'd like to have them aligned, so I supposed the right way to do it was with tables. I'm not sure if that's the best idea. Here is a code I'm using now:

```
\begin{tabular}{l l l}

(4) & a. & \specialcell[t]{Anna \textbf{kauft} heute ein Kleid. \\ 
\textit{Anna buys today a dress}} \\

& b. & \specialcell[t]{Anna will heute ein Kleid \textbf{kaufen}. \\
\textit{Anna wants today a dress buy}} \\

\end{tabular}
```

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

My question is, what's the right code to have it look this way, and still have a continuous numbering, like I managed to do with the simple sentences?
Should I even use tables, because I will have 'real' tables in my document, with a numbering of their own, so maybe I should not mix them up? 
Maybe I should be using a different code altogether?

Comment: Why don't you use nested `enumerate` environments? Is the  indentation the problem ?

Comment: Because I'm a total LaTeX beginner, and probably too stupid, yet. Could you give an example of how that would look (in code and compiled)?

Comment: I can't do this in the comments and I do not want to post an answer before I really understand the question. Do I understand it correctly that the indentation is important for you? Sorry, if my first comment sounded harsh - it was not meant to be.

Comment: You might benefit from the [gb4e package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gb4e/).

Comment: I was too fast in answering and agree with @GarethWalker. Should I delete my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [gb4e](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gb4e/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{xlist}
\ex
\gll  Anna kauft heute ein Kleid\\
     Anna buys today a dress\\
\trans `Anna buys a dress today'
\ex 
Anna kauft heute ein Kleid
\trans `Anna buys a dress today'
\end{xlist}
\ex
\gll  Anna kauft heute ein Kleid\\
     Anna buys today a dress\\
\end{exe}
\begin{exe}
\ex Anna buys a dress today
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of this package for linguistics, but it's exactly what I need. I still have to figure out how to use it, when I only have one or two English sentences that do not require a direct and proper translation.

Comment: The updated code shows some further features. Is there something you want to do not covered there?

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful, and I could figure the last thing I needed out for myself (i.e. have two or more examples, but no glosses or translations).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use nested `enumerate` environments. The `enumerate` package provides the option of adding parameters to the `enumerate` environment in square brackets which both indicates the numbering style. The command `\setcounter{enumi}{3}` sets the current counter for the first level of enumerate to 3. At the next occurrence of `\item` it will be increased by one, so the next `\item` produces the result `(4)`.

In the following, I changed your second example into an example using two `enumerate` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\setcounter{enumi}{3}
\item \begin{enumerate}[a.]
    \item Anna \textbf{kauft} heute ein Kleid. \\ 
      \textit{Anna buys today a dress}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Anna will heute ein Kleid \textbf{kaufen}. \\
    \textit{Anna wants today a dress buy}
  \end{enumerate} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Is this the result you would like to have?

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but Gareth answer was even better, because it was for linguistic examples, and there you prefer to have the words aligned with the first example sentence's words.